# Django queryset for foreign attributes

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I have to select a result table according to this:
Select Session --> Select Course --> Here all student's result will be shown

The problem is I cannot query all the specific students attended the course of that session.

My model for result:

```
class Course(models.Model):
    cid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)

class Student(models.Model):
    sroll = models.IntegerField()

class Teacher(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Session(models.Model):
    sesid = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True,verbose_name= ('Session'))

class Registration(models.Model):
    session = models.ForeignKey(Session, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    course = models.ForeignKey(Course, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Assignation(models.Model):
    reg = models.ForeignKey(Registration, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    teacher = models.ForeignKey(Teacher, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)

class Result(models.Model):
    asign = models.ForeignKey(Assignation, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    student = models.ForeignKey(Student, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    ct1 = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
```

My views.py has:

```
@method_decorator(login_required, name='dispatch')
class SelectSession(ListView):
    template_name = 'Dashboard/selectsession.html'
    model = Session
    fields = ['sesid']

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Session.objects.all()

@method_decorator(login_required, name='dispatch')
class SelectCourse(ListView):
    template_name = 'Dashboard/selectcourse.html'
    model = Course, Registration
    fields = ['all']

    def get_queryset(self):
        course = Registration.objects.filter(session_id=self.kwargs['pk'])
        return course

@method_decorator(login_required, name='dispatch')
class BatchResult(ListView):
    template_name = 'Dashboard/batchResult.html'
    model = Result,Student,Registration,Assignation
    fields = ['all']

    def get_queryset(self):
        result=Result.objects.filter(???=self.kwargs['pk'])
        return result
```

Comment: I think your models structure is not in the  right way that you want to use these. And moreover there is no relation between the course and session

Comment: class Registration(models.Model):
    session = models.ForeignKey(Session, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    course = models.ForeignKey(Course, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `pk` use `session_pk` to maintain code readability.

Instead of `session_id` it should be `session` under `get_queryset()` function in `SelectCource` class

```
 def get_queryset(self):
    course = Registration.objects.filter(session=self.kwargs['pk'])
    return course
```

Also for a particular session, there will be multiple courses which means the `course` response will have multiple objects in it -

```
 def get_queryset(self):
    course = Registration.objects.filter(session=self.kwargs['pk'])
    assignation_objects = Assignation.objects.filter(reg__in=course)
    result = Result.objects.filter(assign__in=assignation_objects )
    return result
```

Refer Queryset API Reference https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#in for more details on working with queryset's